# Show that the following is a tautology, without using truth tables: $[(p\to q)\wedge(q\to r)]\to(p\to r)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> I'm trying to show that the following is a tautology, *without* using truth tables.
>
> $$[(p\to q)\wedge(q\to r)]\to(p\to r)$$

[original problem image (item (b))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoGhL.png)

---

I've tried this:

$$ \neg [(\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee r)] \vee (\neg p \vee r)$$

$$\neg (\neg p \vee q) \vee \neg(\neg q \vee r) \vee (\neg p \vee r)$$

But I'm not sure what to do after this. I've tried distributing the negation operator using DeMorgan's law, and I've also tried FOILing the results, but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a proof of the statement I created with openlogicproject.org.

[image]

A good general practice when you want to prove things with implication like $A\to B$ is to assume $A$ as a hypothesis and see if you can prove $B$ from it.  If so, then you can infer the implication.

Answer (score 2):

There are many methods besides truth-tables, but let's use equivalences, since that seems to be what you tried as well:

DeMorgan gives you:

$$(p \land \neg q) \lor (q \land \neg r) \lor (\neg p \lor r)$$

Now notice that you can drop the last set of parentheses, because they are all $\lor$'s:

$$(p \land \neg q) \lor (q \land \neg r) \lor \neg p \lor r$$

Distribute the $\neg p$ over the $p \land \neg q$, and the $r$ over the $q \land \neg r$:

$$[(p \lor \neg p) \land (\neg q \lor \neg p)] \lor [(q \lor r) \land (\neg r \lor r)]$$

Simplify with tautologies:

$$[\top \land (\neg q \lor \neg p)] \lor [(q \lor r) \land \top]$$

$$(\neg q \lor \neg p) \lor (q \lor r)$$

Again, we can drop parentheses:

$$\neg q \lor \neg p \lor q \lor r$$

And deal with tautologies:

$$\top\lor \neg p \lor r$$

$$\top$$

Answer (score 0):

Would it make sense to reformulate the logical implications as sets? I'd think that $p \to q$ is equivalent to $q \subset p$, though, as I'm not a mathematician *equivalent* might be inadequate in this context. You'd have 
$$\left[ \left( q \subset p \right) \land \left( r \subset q \right) \right] \to r \subset p$$

which is easily shown.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your step:

$\neg [(\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee r)] \vee (\neg p \vee r)$

$\equiv (p \wedge \neg q) ~ \vee (q \wedge \neg r) ~ \vee (\neg p) \vee (r)$

Now write

$\neg p$ as $\neg p \wedge (q \vee \neg q) \equiv (\neg p \wedge q) \vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q)$

and

$r$ as $r \wedge (q \vee \neg q) \equiv (q \wedge r) \vee (\neg q \wedge r)$

Finally

1. combine the terms 
   $p \wedge \neg q$ and $\neg p \wedge \neg q$ to get $\neg q$
2. combine the terms
   $q \wedge \neg r$ and $q \wedge r$ to get $q$

We are left with

$(q) \vee (\neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge q) \vee (\neg q \wedge r)$

and you are done!

Comment: Why not just let $q \vee (\neg q)$ be True? When I combined, nothing happened.

Comment: Fixed... Thanks a lot for pointing out.

Comment: Could you follow all the steps? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Under the Curry-Howard correspondence, it's enough to exhibit a term of type $$[(p \to q) \wedge (q \to r)] \to p \to r$$

This is very easy:

```
answer (f , g) p = g (f p)
```